# If you release a browser game to the web. How do you prevent people from making a copy out of your game?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Apologies in advance if I'm missing something obvious here. But to my knowledge, all the code: css, html and JS, are available to anyone visiting your website (or playing your game on the web). How do they prevent people from stealing the original content?

Comment: preventing? Easy: You can't. 
You can do the same as everyone else "make it as hard as possible"

Comment: On of the thing you could do is make sure some important part of the game logic sits on a server you control and have some authentication to access the api. But that also means you need a server infrastructure to support your game and it won't keep peaople from downloading the assets like the sprites and music of the game

Answer (score 2):

You can use obfuscating tools to make your code less readable.
Also it's possible to make it harder to open devtools on your website.

But it is still not enough. You cannot just prevent somebody from doing something on the Internet. **Everything you release to the web is accessible and copyable.**